# Recargar Eventos Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Al presionar el botón "btn_insert", una vez que se guardan los datos, necesito que se actualicen los eventos, y para ello estoy usando .fullCalendar ('refetchEvents') que debería de recargar los eventos, pero no lo hace y no se porque. Les dejo el código.

Esto es el código de fullcalendar, que trae los eventos de la Base de Datos

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url();?>cCalendar/geteventos',
function(data){

 //alert(data); 

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },

  defaultDate: new Date(),
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  businessHours: true, // display business hours
  editable: true,
  events: $.parseJSON(data),

  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

    date_last_clicked = $(this);
    $(this).css('background-color', '#bed7f3');
    $('#modal_registrar').modal();

   },


   minTime: "08:30:00",
   maxTime: "23:00:00"

});


});
```

La función para guardar los datos

```
$("#btn_insert").click(function(){

 var rut_usu = $("#rut_usu").val();
 var rut_estu = $("#rut_estu").val();
 var id_mot = $("#id_mot").val();
 var fecha_ini = $("#fecha_ini").val();
 var fecha_ter = $("#fecha_ter").val();


 $.ajax({

  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "cCalendar/insertar_cita/",
  type: 'post',
  data: { "rut_usu": rut_usu, "rut_estu": rut_estu, "id_mot" : id_mot , "fecha_ini": fecha_ini , "fecha_ter": fecha_ter},

  success: function(response){ 

       $("#modal_registrar").modal('hide');
       document.getElementById("form_ingresar").reset();
       $("#modal_confirmar").modal('show');
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar("refetchEvents");

       //console.log(response);
   }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

No se si el componente que estes usando sea este https://fullcalendar.io/
La existencia de esa función no la conocia, pero ademas en mi caso particular que refrescara completo no me ayudaba mucho porque necesitaba que actualizara los eventos pero permaneciera en el mismo lugar. Eso lo logré con estas lineas de abajo

```
var actual = $('#calendar-place').fullCalendar('getDate');
$('#calendar-place').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(((m === 0) ? y - 1 : y) + '-' + m + '-' + d));
$('#calendar-place').fullCalendar('gotoDate', actual);
```

En las cuales lo que hago es anvegar hacia atras y hacia la posición original en la fecha del calendario, así se recargaban donde estaba originalmente.

Comment: Consulta, pero lo tendría que agregar dentro del  success: function(response) ? porque lo hice, y sigue sin actualizar, podría recargar la pagina completa...pero no es la idea.. ya que necesito filtrar los horarios por medio de parámetros, lo de .fullCalendar ('refetchEvents')  era para versiones anteriores, la actual es   .fullCalendar( 'updateEvents', events)  aunque tampoco me dio resultado :C     https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvents/

Comment: Si precisamente era ahi donde debias ponerlo

Comment: Y en la consola del navegador no te muestra ningún error

Comment: No...ese es el asunto... :C no recarga los eventos  T.T

Answer (score 1):

Para recargar los eventos debes recargar el calendario, es simple, yo lo hago de esta forma:

```js
        $('#myModalDatosCalendario').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

            $("#calendarioDatos").fullCalendar('render');

        });
```

"$("#CalendarID").fullCalendar('render');"

Solo esta linea te lo refresca, la tengo dentro de un modal por que es donde lo cargo, Espero te sirva, saludos!